# gitpython: Command syntax for git commit

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, gitpython

with using **gitpython** module, I am writing python script to check *git diff --> git add* of all modified files one by one. At the end I want to commit all these changes, but I didn't find the exact syntax of the command.

I'm trying with below code, 'git add' works perfectly but 'git commit' gives error.

```
import git

repo = git.Repo(os.getcwd())
files = repo.git.diff(None, name_only=True)
for f in files.split('\n'):
    show_diff(f)
    repo.git.add(f)

repo.git.commit('test commit', author='sunilt@xxx.com')
```

Here is the error I'm seeing, it seems the something is missing in cmd arguments.

```
In [10]: repo.git.commit("test commit", author="sunilt@xxx.com")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GitCommandError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b4505b7c53c2> in <module>()
----> 1 repo.git.commit("test commit", author="sunil.thorat@nuance.com")

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.pyc in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    421         if name[0] == '_':
    422             return LazyMixin.__getattr__(self, name)
--> 423         return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name,    *args, **kwargs)
    424
    425     def set_persistent_git_options(self, **kwargs):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.pyc in _call_process(self, method, *args, **kwargs)
    866         call.extend(args)
    867
--> 868         return self.execute(call, **_kwargs)
    869
    870     def _parse_object_header(self, header_line):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.pyc in execute(self, command, istream, with_extended_output, with_exceptions, as_process, output_stream, stdout_as_string, kill_after_timeout, with_stdout, universal_newlines, shell, **subprocess_kwargs)
    684
    685         if with_exceptions and status != 0:
--> 686             raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
    687
    688         if isinstance(stdout_value, bytes) and stdout_as_string:  # could also be output_stream

GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git commit --author=sunilt@xxx.com test commit
  stderr: 'error: pathspec 'test commit' did not match any file(s) known to      git.'
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-index-object) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen a better response might be how to apply the documentation to the question at hand. There are levels of understanding. The documentation in its current status can be at times confusing depending on what level you're starting.  I've recently adopted this library but the amount questions I see pointing straight back to the documentation probably should be more indicative that the documentation just isn't doing a good job.  The currently accepted answer here is just an example of how unhelpful the documentation is as it is defaulting to the catchall command that GitPython offers.

Comment: here's an example of the type of interaction I view as somewhat helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915801/2128265 - notice that I'm not just pointing to documentation but showing how to apply it. RTFM-esque comments are toxic and only silence questions, ultimately hurting the use of the corresponding package.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Resolved the issue, need to add "-m" flag in the commit command as below:

```
repo.git.commit('-m', 'test commit', author='sunilt@xxx.com')
```