# Git push via GitPython

Tags: python, git, push, gitpython

I have this code in Python (using "import git"):

```
repo = git.Repo("my_repository")
repo.git.add("bla.txt")
repo.git.commit("my commit description")
```

Now I want to push this commit. I've tried a lot with no success. The Python command should be similar to this Bash command:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Answer (score 33):

Following is the code to `git add`, `git commit` and then `git push` using  [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Install [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using `pip install gitpython`.

```
from git import Repo

PATH_OF_GIT_REPO = r'path\to\your\project\folder\.git'  # make sure .git folder is properly configured
COMMIT_MESSAGE = 'comment from python script'

def git_push():
    try:
        repo = Repo(PATH_OF_GIT_REPO)
        repo.git.add(update=True)
        repo.index.commit(COMMIT_MESSAGE)
        origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
        origin.push()
    except:
        print('Some error occured while pushing the code')    

git_push()
```

Comment: Is there a way to enter the password via python?

Comment: @nerdguy TIPS: do a little search on git ssh. will make life a lot easier and secure. no need to use password and http :)

Comment: configure git using git ssh environment setup to work from command line without user inputting username / password.  keep passwords out of code.

Comment: I get empty pushes to the repo?

Comment: [the api for git pull](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.Remote.pull) says `kwargs – Additional arguments to be passed to git-pull`. So can I directly use `repo.git.pull()` without using [`remote()`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.remote) to specify `the remote` branch? I see Shaghaji answer, that is not clear to me regarding the positional parameters. I cannot see it in the doks.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following. It may have your problem solved...

```
repo.git.pull('origin', new_branch)
repo.git.push('origin', new_branch)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using Index ([documented a little bit here](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-index-object)) like so:

```py
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('path/to/git/repo')  # if repo is CWD just do '.'

repo.index.add(['bla.txt'])
repo.index.commit('my commit description')
origin = repo.remote('origin')
origin.push()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation page of `gitpython` http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html. You have to define a remote repo with something like `origin = repo.create_remote('origin', repo.remotes.origin.url)`

then `origin.pull()`

I would look at the whole example in the documentation in the section "Handling Remotes"

Here is the full example from the documentation

```
empty_repo = git.Repo.init(osp.join(rw_dir, 'empty'))
origin = empty_repo.create_remote('origin', repo.remotes.origin.url)
assert origin.exists()
assert origin == empty_repo.remotes.origin == empty_repo.remotes['origin']
origin.fetch()                  # assure we actually have data. fetch() returns useful information
# Setup a local tracking branch of a remote branch
empty_repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master)  # create local branch "master" from remote "master"
empty_repo.heads.master.set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master)  # set local "master" to track remote "master
empty_repo.heads.master.checkout()  # checkout local "master" to working tree
# Three above commands in one:
empty_repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master).checkout()
# rename remotes
origin.rename('new_origin')
# push and pull behaves similarly to `git push|pull`
origin.pull()
origin.push()
# assert not empty_repo.delete_remote(origin).exists()     # create and delete remotes
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this example but it still didn't work for me... There is an error in the first line origin = repo.create_remote('origin', repo.remotes.origin.url): "git remote add origin ssh:........ returned exit status 128: fatal: remote origin already exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: if someone can help I'll so appreciate it :)

Comment: This example makes no sense. `repo.create_remote('origin', repo.remotes.origin.url)` is creating the 'origin' remote by referencing the url of the 'origin' remote??? If `repo.remotes.origin` is not None then you already have the origin remote and can just simply do `repo.remotes.origin.push()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by calling

```
repo.git.push("origin", "HEAD:refs/for/master")
```