# How to add/commit and push a repository via git-python?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to use git-python to add, commit and push to a repository. Following the incomplete documentation and an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836988/git-push-via-gitpython) I tried it the following way:

```py
myrepo = Repo('Repos/hello-world/.git')
# make changes to README.md
myrepo.index.add('README.md')
myrepo.index.commit("Updating copyright year")
myrepo.git.push("origin", "copyright_updater")   ###
```

I checked out the repository `hello_world` and put it under a folder `Repos`. I did change a single file, the `README.md`. But with that code I get an error

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
   cmdline: git push origin copyright_updater
   stderr: 'error: src refspec copyright_updater does not match any.
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:alex4200/hello-world.git''
```

in the marked line.

How can I fix it, in order to push the changes to a new branch and to create a pull request on GitHub?

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is to use `git` directly. This is explained at the ***end*** of the [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) tutorial.

Basically, when you have a `repo` object, you can call every git function like

```
repo.git.function(param1, param2, param3, ...)
```

so for example, to call the git command

```
git push --set-upstream origin testbranch
```

you do

```
repo.git.push("--set-upstream", "origin", "testbranch")
```

Special rules concerning '-' applies.

So the full sequence, in order to create a new branch and push it to github, becomes

```
repo = Repo('Repos/hello-world/.git')
# make changes to README.md
repo.index.add('README.md')
repo.index.commit("My commit message")
repo.git.checkout("-b", "new_branch")
repo.git.push("--set-upstream","origin","new_branch")
```

How you create a pull request on github for the new branch, is some different magic I do not master yet...

Comment: Pull requests are not part of Git. Pull requests on GitHub use GitHub URLs and sequences; pull requests on Bitbucket use bitbucket URLs and sequences (different from those on GitHub); and so on.