# How do you push files to a github repo in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a file called `w.txt` that holds 4 random numbers
I am trying to push it to a git repo and I have the following code:

```
    aa=open(fileName,'r').read()
    print(aa)
    text= base64.b64encode(aa.encode("utf-8"))
    api="https://api.github.com/repos/Ixonblitz-MatOS/Worm/contents/w.txt"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f'''Bearer {token}''',
        "Content-type": "application/vnd.github+json"
    }
    data = {
        "message": msg, # Put your commit message here.
        "content": text.decode("utf-8")
    }

    r = requests.put(api, headers=headers, json=data)
    print(r.text)
```

In this case `fileName` is `"w.txt"` and the api is the api for my repo and the correct token is being used. What am I missing? It is leaving the file on my repo empty instead of putting the numbers there.

Comment: What is coming back from `print(r.text)`? What is `r.status_code`. I believe a successful status_code is `201`.  If it isn't `201`, what is the contents of `response.json()['message']`?

Comment: `r.text` returns `'{"message":"Invalid request.\\n\\n\\"sha\\" wasn\'t supplied.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}'`

Comment: `status_code` is `422`

Comment: Also, I may be off base here since I haven't attempted myself, but the examples I find online suggest that the token in the header is formatted like `'token {token}'`, not`'bearer {token}'`. But... perhaps this is another form of auth that the examples don't include.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Still recieve `{"message":"Invalid request.\n\n\"sha\" wasn't supplied.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}` in `r.text`

Comment: [Related](https://community.n8n.io/t/error-github-error-response-422-invalid-request-sha-wasnt-supplied/5298)?

Comment: @WakemeUpNow That was where I was headed, digging into this, I've seen a few folks suggest that if trying to create a file that already exists on base branch, then you will get this message.

Comment: This actually worked it was because instead of actively updating an existing file it tries to create one causing the issue

Comment: Then that lwaves me the question how you actively update or delete a file in python with it

Comment: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/avullo/b8153522f015a8b908072833b95c3408) suggests it's kind of ugly. You pull down the tree, find the file, get the sha, package your change, include the sha, and shoot it back at the API. :/

Comment: Oh how do you pull down the tree I haven't used this API very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the SHA of the file as the error message says.

To get the SHA, you can [get](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content) the file like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/Ixonblitz-MatOS/Worm/contents/w.txt"

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
```

The SHA will be at `data['sha']`.

Then you need to modify your request to include the SHA:

```py
    data = {
        "message": msg, # Put your commit message here.
        "content": text.decode("utf-8"),
        "sha": data['sha']
    }
```

The `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}`  API route to fetch files has some size limits. See below:

> If the requested file's size is:
>
> - 1 MB or smaller: All features of this endpoint are supported.
> - Between
>   1-100 MB: Only the raw or object custom media types are supported.
>   Both will work as normal, except that when using the object media
>   type, the content field will be an empty string and the encoding field
>   will be "none". To get the contents of these larger files, use the raw
>   media type.
> - Greater than 100 MB: This endpoint is not supported.

For larger files, you will have to [clone the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472552/python-way-to-clone-a-git-repository) and then [calculate the SHA locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index#24283352).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111480/14240615) way.

```
from git import Repo

PATH_OF_GIT_REPO = r'path\to\your\project\folder\.git'  # make sure .git folder is properly configured
COMMIT_MESSAGE = 'comment from python script'

def git_push():
    try:
        repo = Repo(PATH_OF_GIT_REPO)
        repo.git.add(update=True)
        repo.index.commit(COMMIT_MESSAGE)
        origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
        origin.push()
    except:
        print('Some error occured while pushing the code')    

git_push()
```